# Can i run 'ls' on text file that contain list of files and directories?

Tags: ls

I have a text file that contain list of files and directories and i want to filter only the files. I tried this but it didn't worked: `cat file.txt | ls -l | grep ^-`. This is the file:

```
/etc
/etc/firefox-esr
/etc/firefox-esr/firefox-esr.js
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/firefox
package diverts others to: /usr/bin/firefox.real
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/firefox-esr
/usr/lib/firefox-esr/Throbber-small.gif
/usr/lib/firefox-esr/application.ini
/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser
/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/blocklist.xml
/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/chrome.manifest
/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/crashreporter-override.ini
/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features
/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/formautofill@mozilla.org.xpi
/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/fxmonitor@mozilla.org.xpi
/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/screenshots@mozilla.org.xpi
/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/webcompat-reporter@mozilla.org.xpi
/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
```

etc.

Comment: What do you actually want? An `ls -l` for the files/directories listed in that file?

Comment: Yes, but to filter only files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat file.txt | ls -l` would produce the contents of the file to the *standard input* of `ls`, it just doesn't read anything from there. Usually stdin is connected to the terminal, and you never really type anything for `ls` when it's running. It does read from the command line though, so you could put the contents of the file there, with command substitution:

```
ls -ld $(cat file.txt) | grep ^-
```

The `-d` is there so that `ls` doesn't list the contents of directories.

However, there a the usual caveats regarding word splitting here, lines with spaces will be broken to multiple parts, and `ls` would e.g. look for files called 
`package`, `diverts`, and `others`. Also, wildcards in the filenames would be expanded. To prevent that, we'd need to disable globbing with `set -f` and set `IFS` to split only on newlines. Assuming Bash:

```
(set -f; IFS=$'\n'; ls -ld $(cat file.txt) | grep ^- )
```

An alternative would be to loop over the file contents in the shell and test if the lines represent names of directories or not.

Comment: I think this will do the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to parse the permission string off the front of an `ls` output, I think I'd do it this way:

```
while IFS= read -r filepath; do 
  test -f "$filepath" && echo "$filepath: is an ordinary file"
done < file.txt
```

You could use the `[ -f "$filepath" ]` form of `test` if you prefer.